# Why does my stack object change a default value after being created?

Tags: c++, class, object, stack

So I have a stack created as below. The variable *top* is supposed to represent the current index, or the "top index". So by doing some testing, the constructor *does* get called and the value of top *is* -1 while the program is still running the constructor method. However, after creating the stack object, and testing to see what the value of *top* is, I keep getting top to be 32767. Literally, all that main does is create a new stack as

```
 Stack s; //Testing while this is running to see value of top... I get -1
 //Testing here to see value of top... I get 32767
```

-

The stack is created as shown below.

```
 #ifndef __STACK_H_
 #define __STACK_H_

  class Stack{
    int stackSize;
    int top;
    char* items;
  public:
    Stack();
    ~Stack();
    void push(char c);
    char pop();
    bool isFull();
    bool isEmpty();
 };

 #endif
```

And the implementation as below:

```
 /* STACK IMPLEMENTATION FILE */

 #include "stack.h"
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 Stack::Stack(){
    cout << "Ctor is run." << endl;
    stackSize = 10; //Stack Size is 10
    int top = -1; //Currently empty stack
    cout << top << endl;
    items = new char[stackSize];
 }

 Stack::~Stack(){ //Destructor
    delete[] items;
 }

 void Stack::push(char c){ //Push next into stack
    items[++top] = c;
    cout << top << endl;
 }


 char Stack::pop(){ //Pop one from stack
    return items[top--];
 }

 bool Stack::isFull(){ //Checks to see if stack is full
    if (top + 1 == stackSize) return true;
 }

 bool Stack::isEmpty(){ //Checks to see if stack is empty
    if (top == -1) return true;
 }
```

Comment: `isFull` and `isEmpty` don't return anything if their `if` tests fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `top = 1` not `int top = 1` in your constructor. The former assigns to the member, the latter initialises a local variable that goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

Comment: Ah such a silly little mistake I spent hours trying to figure out. Thanks Alan!